# SCons Binary Directory

Tags: unix, scons

How is the binary/executable directory specified in SCons? It's easy to do as follows:

```
Program( target = 'bin/helloworld', source = 'src/helloworld.cc' )
```

The problem with this approach is when trying to do cross-platform builds. Here's an example that works:

```
StaticLibrary( target = 'helloworld', source = 'src/helloworldlib.cc' )
```

The output of this on a Unix system is a library named libhelloworld.a. An example where it doesn't work follows:

```
StaticLibrary( target = 'lib/helloworld', source = 'src/helloworldlib.cc' )
```

The output on a Unix system of this is a file helloworld.a in directory lib. This causes problems when LIBS is specified as ['helloworld'], which is the cross platform way to do it.

What is the parameter name to pass into StaticLibrary, SharedLibrary, and Program to output binaries into a directory other than the base directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c3340.html) suggests that you use a variant directory and a SConscript file in the source directory. In your example, place a SConscript file in the `src` directory:

```
StaticLibrary(target="helloworld", source="helloworldlib.cc")
```

and call that from the main SConstruct file:

```
SConscript("src/SConscript", variant_dir="lib")
```

Comment: Variant doesn't control this. It's decided by wherever the SCon* file is located.